# Terminate EC2 Instance When DDoS'd, Then Launch New Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ddos

I'm planning on migrating my website and API to `EC2` on Amazon. If one of my `EC2` `instances` were to be DDoS'd, can I `terminate` the `instance`, then launch a new `instance` and update my CloudFlare DNS records to the new `EC2` `instance's` IP all in an effort to mitigate the DDoS attack? I have an `AMI` for my website and API created from an `EC2` `instance` so I can easily launch new `instance's` and have the new server ready to go in around 5 minutes. Would Amazon allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the [AWS DDOS Whitepaper](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/aws-best-practices-for-ddos-resiliency-updated-whitepaper-now-available/).

A couple of ideas:

- If you get a DDOS attack turn on the CloudFlare "I'm Under Attack" feature. That will help mitigate the attack. Of course you must have firewalled your instance so only CloudFlare IPs can reach your infrastructure. This on its own is probably sufficient to mitigate a DDOS attack.
- Put an ELB (or ALB) in front of your instance(s). It provides AWS Shield, which gives you reasonably good DDOS protection. I wonder if the CloudFlare IPs would be considered attacking your site, as a relatively small number (hundreds of IPS I guess) will be sending all the traffic to your instance. This could cut off legitimate traffic.
- AWS WAF provides additional DDOS protection. Not sure if you want to use it with CloudFlare as well.
- If all else fails and you need to change IPs you don't need a new instance. Just detach and deallocate your elastic IP, allocate and attach a new elastic IP. There might be some configuration required at the OS level. This should be a last resort though, as it will take time for all your clients to get the new IP.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could, but that seems like overkill to be honest. Why not utilize API Gateway's Throttling feature?

> To prevent your API from being overwhelmed by too many requests, Amazon API Gateway throttles requests to your API using the token bucket algorithm, where a token counts for a request. Specifically, API Gateway sets a limit on a steady-state rate and a burst of request submissions against all APIs in your account. In the token bucket algorithm, the burst is the maximum bucket size.

Also read this: https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-ddos-attack-mitigation/

Comment: This really only helps protect APIs, rather than web servers.